# How to hide footer component that appear on keyboard's top when editText gets focused in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, uiscrollview

[image]

Fragment layout
[image]

Actually the footer is set inside an activity class and the edittext is placed inside a fragment.
manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name="HomeController"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"/>
```

Inside my fragment class I added

```
 getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

These are the code snippet that I used, but it won't work!
Note: in Fragment UI, the whole screen has a scroll view,
Don't know why it is happening like this?Actually I don't want my footer on the keyboard's top.
Any suggestions on how to solve this behavior? And its appriciatble for the replies :)

Comment: upload your fragment layout also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your activity.

I did not test, but this might work. it is a bad way though(

```
 contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
    
        Rect r = new Rect();
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int screenHeight = rootView.getHeight();
    
        // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
        // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
        int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;
    
        Log.d(TAG, "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);
    
        if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
            // keyboard is opened
            //set bottom navigation(footer) bar to View.GONE
        }
        else {
            // keyboard is closed
           //set bottom navigation bar(footer) to View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) I have one doubt, is this contentView is parentLayout?

Comment: @varshajeevan ups! yeah, it is. I copied it from my old utils file, that's why the inconsistency(. I updated the answer. Probably you could just use parent layout.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Its worked properly. what I have done is I disabled my bottom bar when the keyboard show and enabled when the keyboard gets hide.

Comment: You r welcome! But as i said this is not a good way... since it may misbehave on some phones ( i personally didnt have any issue so far), and maybe on splitscreen mode.

Comment: ohhk... lemme check this:)

Answer (score 0):

Use android:windowSoftInputMode="hidden" in your parent layout in the xml file. also in case it has layoutAbove property then try to remove it.

Comment: Here I have a parent layout (Relative Layout), in this layout I used Scroll view, and added whole design inside this view.

Comment: sorry, it's not working, I added  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in my parent layout and changed whole layout above property :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following in manifest file:
**android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"**

Also remove the following from fragment:
**getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);**

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Kamran Sajid, But it won't work :(